# function requiring more than one return statements

Tags: java, function, if-statement, return-value

I am posting here two functions. In the `findPrime(int m, int i, int n)` I have one outer if and outer else block from both the block I am getting return so it can be considered that the function is returning something I put same structure in `endOther(String a, String b)` i.e. 
there are two main if-else blocks both are returning value as per function's return type so we can say that function is returning something but the `endOther(String a, String b)`
function is throwing compile time error saying that put return statement while first function is not throwing such error. I am not understanding this issue please help me. Type both the functions in eclipse and check

**1.**

```
static boolean findPrime(int m, int i, int n){
    if(n == 0 || n == 1)
        return false;
    else {
        if(i <= m) {
            if(n%i == 0)
                //if(m%i == 0)
                return false;
            else {
                i++;
                //return findPrime(m,i);
                return findPrime(m,i,n);
            }

        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**2.**

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
    if(a.length()==b.length()) {
        if(a.equals(b))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else {
        if(a.length()>b.length()) {
            if(a.substring(a.length()-b.length(),b.length()).equals(b))
                return true;
        }
        else { 
            if(b.substring(b.length()-a.length(),a.length()).equals(a))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `String.equals` returns a Boolean (`true` or `false`). You don't need to do `if(a.equals(b)) return true; else return false;`, you can just `return a.equals(b);`

Answer (score 2):

Your `endOther` function must return a value on all possible execution paths. In case `a.length() > b.length()` the return may not be executed based on the condition of the inner if.

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
    if(a.length()==b.length()) {
        if(a.equals(b))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else {
        if(a.length()>b.length()) {
            // IF THIS FAILS THERE IS NO RETURN!
            if(a.substring(a.length()-b.length(),b.length()).equals(b))
                return true;
        }
        else { 
            if(b.substring(b.length()-a.length(),a.length()).equals(a))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As a general note, you could use some of the methods in `String` to improve your code, e.g. `String.endsWith` instead of the substring operation. This would be more readable. `a` and `b` being identical is a special case of `String.endsWith`, so the following should be equivalent:

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
    return a.endsWith(b) || b.endsWith(a);
}
```

Comment: Or `return a.length() == b.length() ? a.equals(b) : a.length() > b.length() ? a.endsWith(b) : b.endsWith(a);`. Or even `return a.endsWith(b) || b.endsWith(a);`